# Remote access to postgresql server windows 10

Tags: postgresql

As the title suggest I'm trying to configure a postgresql server to be accessible remotely. I've followed many guides and viewed some of the other answers here however I'm still having trouble.

The details:
os, windows 10

postgresql version on host is 11.6

postgresql version on remote is 11.2 with anaconda install

I have changed the pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf to allow for connections to the server.
More specifically I've added the line

`host all all xxx.xx.x.0/0 trust`

I can verify that the host is listening on local address 0.0.0.0:5432 via netstat.
I can ping the ip of the host from the remote, and I have set windows firewalls on the host to allow connection.

Yet I still recieve the following error when trying to access psql from the remote.

````
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "xxx.xx.x.144" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?```
````

Comment: What sits between the remote and the database?  Connections can be blocked local to the server, but also on any firewall, router, gateway between them.

Comment: The machines are connected via company network, I think we are using a switchbox.

Comment: You will probably need to ask your company's network engineers, then.  If the database won't talk to you, you should get an immediate "connection refused".  Connection timed out (when network connectivity does exist) is almost always something intentionally interfering with you.

Comment: Run the SQL statement `SHOW listen_addresses` on the server and see if you get `*` as you should. A firewall can also block and allow connections based on protocol and port.

Answer (score 0):

I had to double check the windows firewall permissions. The connection was enabled but the application was not set to allowed. It turns out a local user can enable connection but I needed the system admin to set the application executable to allowed by the windows fire wall.